# DNS resolution via Proxy in Java

Tags: java, proxy, dns

In our enterprise network we have to use a proxy to reach the internet. For some services there are set up VPNs connecting to external partners.
Unfortunately some of them can't guarantee a static IP address therefore they usually create public DNS entries.
So these DNS entries are publicly accessible but point to IP addresses that are only reachable from our network through the VPN.

Would it be possible to ask the proxy to do only the DNS resolution and return the IP address?